# Why is my Django object deleted with no reason?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I know this question may not be in appropriate shape, but I have no other way to describe it.
I have a Django project, deployed with Heroku. I'm using Postgres add-on. The problem is, few of the objects that my users created is being deleted for some reason. I tried to see if there's a pattern with this issue, but I haven't found one. It happens randomly.
 (This usually happens when I share(copy+paste) a user's post to other people, but I'm not sure if it's a pattern.)
I know it's not the `heroku ephemeral filesystem` issue, because I'm using the Postgres add-on. So I started wondering if there could be something wrong with Heroku or the Postgres add-on itself.  This is a quite serious issue, but I can't figure out what the problem is.
Has anyone experienced similar issue or knows the answer to this?
Thank you very much.
**Update**
So I've checked my `settings.py`, and I have this :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME' : str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
...
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

However, I'm using Postgres add-on in my Heroku..

Comment: Can you share the model that has the issue, any related models and the views for the model?

Comment: I've been using PostgreSQL in Heroku for a long time, and haven't faced any issues. Are you sure that the Django app is connected to PostgreSQL? and not to the SqLite?

Comment: I'm going to go with @JPG here - most likely your DB config isn't correct. If PG in Heroku randomly deleted stuff there'd be a lot more people shouting about it :)

Comment: @JPG I'm very much confused now. I've checked my `settings.py`, and found out I'm using SQLite. But I'm using Postgres add-on in my Heroku server. (I've updated the post, please check it out). Have I done it wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan, to be totally clear, you are talking about things saved to your database, right? Not uploaded files? If you connect to your Postgres database using some other client, do you see the data you expect?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I can see the data saved in my Django admin. But occasionally few object disappears for no reason.. I know it sounds strange.

Comment: @Ryan, disappears from the database entirely?

Comment: @Chris Well unfortunately I don't know how to check it directly from DB. However the objects are clearly gone in the Django admin as well as the template that (is supposed to) displays it.

Comment: That's not something that tends to just happen for no reason. Can you temporarily [enable logging of all queries to your database](https://help.heroku.com/Y1WV64AZ/can-i-log-all-queries-that-run-on-my-heroku-postgres-database)? Hopefully you'll see some `DELETE` or similar queries coming in to point in the right direction. (Note that this will have a significant performance impact on the database.)

Comment: @Chris Thanks a lot. But I still won't be able to see what happened in the past, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239548/discussion-between-chris-and-ryan).

Comment: @Chris Hi Chris, I realized that I've been running the project with `DEBUG=True` the whole time (about 2 months). Could this be the problem?

Comment: Unlikely. I'm not aware of any reason `DEBUG` would cause data loss. In the chat you mention that you have delete endpoint that is unprotected. I suggest you guard against anonymous delete, but we still don't really know what's going on here.